# Display an "Show All"-Option in DataTable-Paginator-Dropdown in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, pagination

I have Programm in Java, I Use Primefaces Pagination and lazy loading.
I want to add "Show All" In rowsPerPageTemplate.

```
<p:dataTable var="info"
                    value="#{infoMB.lazyModel}"
                    id="infoTable"
                    width="100%"
                    liveResize="true"
                    paginator="true"
                    rows="50"
                    paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="50,100,"Show all" rowsPerPageAllEntry="true"
                    lazy="true">
```

Comment: why not make it in the table header

Comment: thanks for the comment, how in Header ?

Comment: it will look like this `<f:facet name="header" >
                            <p:commandButton  value="Validate button" action="#{managedBean.method()}"   >
                            </p:commandButton> 
                        </f:facet>` it will be directly under `<p:dataTable>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make a commandButton appear in your dataTable fallow this example :

```
<p:dataTable ... >

   <f:facet name="header" > <p:commandButton value="Validate button" action="#{managedBean.method()}" > </p:commandButton> </f:facet>

 </p:dataTable ... >
```

You can even show it in the bottom of your dataTable like this

```
 <p:dataTable ... >

   <f:facet name="footer" > <p:commandButton value="Validate button" action="#{managedBean.method()}" > </p:commandButton> </f:facet>

 </p:dataTable ... >
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your time and for your help

Comment: I am beginner in Java, what is mean action="#{managedBean.method()}" ?

Comment: @AllexFerra it can be any java method `public void method(){ ... } `

Comment: @AllexFerra is there something new ?!?

Comment: This is the most mysteriously accepted answer I have ever seen

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Jaqen H'ghar statement under the comments section that this is the most mysteriously accepted answer I have ever seen. I post here the solution in case for other people looking a solution on this.

I am using **Primefaces-7.0** and took a look at the code of `org/primefaces/component/paginator/RowsPerPageDropDownRenderer.class` and found the code below:

```
if (option.trim().startsWith("{ShowAll|")) {
    optionText = option.substring(option.indexOf("'") + 1, option.lastIndexOf("'"));
    rows = pageable.getRowCount();
  } else {
    optionText = option.trim();
    rows = Integer.parseInt(optionText);
  }
```

So in order to make the example working you should add `{ShowAll|'Show All'`, this will add in the dropdown selector a **Show All ** option which will show you all the rows of your list in one page.

**Example Primefaces-7.0** (`{ShowAll|'Show All'`)

```
<p:dataTable var="info"
                value="#{infoMB.lazyModel}"
                id="infoTable"
                width="100%"
                liveResize="true"
                paginator="true"
                rows="50"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="50,100,{ShowAll|'Show All' " rowsPerPageAllEntry="true"
                lazy="true">
```

**Example Primefaces 6.2** (`*` or `All rows`)

```
<p:dataTable var="info"
            value="#{infoMB.lazyModel}"
            id="infoTable"
            width="100%"
            liveResize="true"
            paginator="true"
            rows="50"
            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="50,100,*" rowsPerPageAllEntry="true"
            lazy="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me. Make the last option in `rowsPerPageTemplate` 999999999.

```
    <script>
        function updateShowAll() {
            $('.ui-paginator-rpp-options').children().each(function() {if ($(this).text() === '999999999'){$(this).text('Show all')}});
        }
        updateShowAll();
        $(document).on('pfAjaxComplete', updateShowAll);
    </script>
```

The event handler is to avoid having to remember to call the js-function manually after `update` of the datatable.

It seems this will be built in in PF 6.1 by using "*".